# Metadata in jsonlite - R

Tags: json, r, metadata, jsonlite

I have a questions regarding metadata in a JSON file using R. I have a dataframe in R and I am using the function `jsonlite::toJSON` to convert it to a JSON file.

However, I would like to add some metadata to the JSON file. Basically to have my JSON output looking like that?

```
{
    "metadata" :{
        "status": "active",
        "msg": "my_message"
    },
    "data" :{
        "id": 1001,
           "name": "Bob"
       }
 }
```

Let me know how I can make it happen !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
df   <- data.frame(id = 1001, name = 'Bob')
meta <- data.frame(status = 'active', msg = 'my_msg')
jsonlite::toJSON(list('metadata'=meta, 'data'=df), pretty = T)
```

which yields

```
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "status": "active",
      "msg": "my_msg"
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1001,
      "name": "Bob"
    }
  ]
}
```

The key idea is to make up a list of metadata and data.

Update due to comment:

```
df   <- data.frame(id = 1001, name = 'Bob')
meta <- list(status = 'active', msg = 'my_msg')
jsonlite::toJSON(list('metadata'=meta, 'data'= df), pretty = F, auto_unbox = T)
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Martin, 
Do you know if you would be possible to have something like that: 
    `{
  "metadata": 
    {
      "status": "active",
      "msg": "my_msg"
    }
  ,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1001,
      "name": "Bob"
    }
  ]
   }` 
Basically, I removed the [] out of the metadata. Thanks !

Comment: Working perfectly again :) Thanks !